# LibGDX - Is actor touched in radius

Tags: android, user-interface, libgdx, actor, stage

I'm trying to add **`Actor`** to **`Stage`** and that actor image's shape is **`Circle`**. I want to detect the touch only in that circle not the rectangle. How could I accomplish that ?

**A bit of backstory:**
I had made UI from **`Sprites`**, and it was working fine. But now I want to change that system to **`Scene2D.UI`** ( it's easier to manipulate this way ( at least for me ) ).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

## Found the solution myself!

You just need to **@Override** the Actor's **hit** method, like so:

```
@Override public Actor hit( float x, float y, boolean touchable )
{
    if( touchable && getTouchable( ) != Touchable.enabled ) return null;
    return area.contains( x, y ) ? this : null;
}
```

P.S. **area** is a **Circle** class object, defined in the Constructor

Comment: Just wanted to post a link to [Scene 2D Hit detection](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#hit-detection) :P

Comment: Great that you found the answer yourself, but maybe you should try to find it a little harder before posting. As you can see, you almost had it :)

Comment: The fun thing is that I was trying to make this for like 2 hours. And, once I posted the question, the answer, somehow, came to my mind...

Comment: @TobLoef It's not wrong to post questions on SO, even if you allready know the solution. It might help others with the same problem. It's just important that the question is clear and fits SO.